# Is it safe to update from 2.6.2 to the newest version?

Tags: updates, wordpress-version, deprecation

I'm using Wordpress version 2.6.2 and now it shows in the page that

```
Deprecated: Assigning the return value of new by reference is deprecated in /home/np14388/domains/<sitename>/public_html/wp-settings.php on line 472
```

etc. Is it safe to update from this version to the newest one, or should I update in certain phases (2.6.2 -> 2.6.3 etc.)? Please help.

Comment: See http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/17541/3898

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably.

Just do the following before updating:

1. Do a direct SQL backup of the database
2. Export your site content
3. Disable all Plugins
4. Switch to the default Theme

Then update to the latest version. If anything goes wrong, just restore from your backups, and try an iterative update.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Yes, you can upgrade all the way.

Long answer: Yes, but backup everything anyway. Just in case. If something goes wrong, you can restore things from the backup.